# MVC PartialView is not populated with model details

Tags: c#, razor, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I intend to display a list of employees with about five columns on the left side of my razor view, and on selecting any employee (row), display details of the employee as a readonly partial view on the right - as in the image below. My wish is to reuse the details form later in another view to add/update records.
[image]

My controller is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mymvc.Controllers
{
    public class EmpController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyEntities _db = new MyEntities();
        private IEnumerable<vEmployee> _Employees;

        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["ModuleName"] = "Active Employees";
            ViewData["deptIDList"] = _db.lu_Department.OrderBy(e => e.Dept);
            ViewData["jobTitleIDList"] = _db.lu_JobTitle.OrderBy(e => e.JobTitle);
            ViewData["genderList"] = _db.lu_Gender.OrderBy(e => e.Gender);
            ViewData["ethnicityList"] = _db.lu_Ethnicity.OrderBy(e => e.Ethnicity);
            ViewData["nationalityList"] = _db.lu_Nationality.OrderBy(e => e.Nationality);
            ViewData["staffLocationList"] = _db.lu_StaffLocation.OrderBy(e => e.StaffLocation);
            ViewData["notchList"] = _db.lu_EmploymentGradeNotch.OrderBy(e => e.Notch);
            ViewData["salutationList"] = _db.lu_Salutation.OrderBy(e => e.Title);
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(int employeeID = 0)
        {
            vEmployee SelectedEmployee = null;
            ViewData["deptIDList"] = _db.lu_Department.OrderBy(e => e.Dept);
            ViewData["jobTitleIDList"] = _db.lu_JobTitle.OrderBy(e => e.JobTitle);
            ViewData["genderList"] = _db.lu_Gender.OrderBy(e => e.Gender);
            ViewData["ethnicityList"] = _db.lu_Ethnicity.OrderBy(e => e.Ethnicity);
            ViewData["nationalityList"] = _db.lu_Nationality.OrderBy(e => e.Nationality);
            ViewData["staffLocationList"] = _db.lu_StaffLocation.OrderBy(e => e.StaffLocation);
            ViewData["notchList"] = _db.lu_EmploymentGradeNotch.OrderBy(e => e.Notch);
            ViewData["salutationList"] = _db.lu_Salutation.OrderBy(e => e.Title);
            try
            {
                if (employeeID == 0)
                    employeeID = _db.Employees.OrderBy(m => m.EmployeeNumber).First().EmployeeID;

                if (_Employees == null)
                    _Employees = GetEmployees();

                SelectedEmployee = _Employees.First(e => e.EmployeeID == employeeID);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var msg = e.Message;
            }
            return View(SelectedEmployee);
        }

        private IEnumerable<vEmployee> GetEmployees()
        {
            IEnumerable<vEmployee> emp = (from e in _db.Employees
                                          join c in _db.Contacts on e.EmployeeID equals c.EmployeeID
                                          join g in _db.lu_EmploymentGradeNotch on e.NotchID equals g.NotchID
                                          join u in _db.lu_Salutation on c.SalutationID equals u.TitleID into sal
                                          from u in sal.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join s in _db.lu_SUBDepartment on e.SubDeptID equals s.SubDeptID into sde
                                          from s in sde.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join l in _db.lu_StaffLocation on e.StaffLocationID equals l.StaffLocationID into cl
                                          from cm in cl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join t in _db.lu_Ethnicity on c.EthnicityID equals t.EthnicityID into eth
                                          from et in eth.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join n in _db.lu_Nationality on c.NationalityID equals n.NationalityID into nt
                                          from nt1 in nt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          where c.ContactTypeID == 1 && e.EmploymentStatusID == 1
                                          select new vEmployee
                                          {
                                              EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
                                              EmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber,
                                              DeptID = e.DeptID,
                                              SubDeptID = e.SubDeptID,
                                              JobTitleID = e.JobTitleID,
                                              ReportsToID = e.ReportsToID,
                                              NotchID = g.NotchID,
                                              HireDate = e.HireDate,
                                              StaffLocationID = e.StaffLocationID,
                                              FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                              LastName = c.LastName,
                                              MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
                                              FullName = c.FirstName + (c.MiddleName == null ? "" : " " + c.MiddleName) + " " + c.LastName + " (" + u.Title + ")",
                                              SalutationID = c.SalutationID,
                                              GenderID = c.GenderID,
                                              EthnicityID = c.EthnicityID,
                                              NationalityID = c.NationalityID,
                                              Photograph = e.Photograph
                                          })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(m => m.EmployeeNumber)
                    .ThenBy(m => m.FirstName);

            return emp;
        }
        public ActionResult ActiveEmployees_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            _Employees = GetEmployees();
            return Json(_Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }    

    }
}
```

My Main Index view:

```
@using Mymvc.Models
@model Mymvc.Models.vEmployee
@using System.Collections

<div class="col col-xs-6">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<vEmployee>()
        .Name("EmployeesList")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeNumber).Width(35);
            columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Width(60);
            columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(60);
            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.JobTitleID, (IEnumerable)ViewData["jobTitleIDList"], "JobTitleID", "JobTitle")
                    .Width(60);
            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DeptID, (IEnumerable)ViewData["deptIDList"], "DeptID", "Dept")
                    .Width(60);
        })
        .Events(e => e.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect"))
        .Events(e => e.DataBound("Grid_OnDataBound"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(15)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error")) // Handle the "error" event
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(m => m.EmployeeID);
                model.Field(m => m.EmployeeID).Editable(false);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("ActiveEmployees_Read", "Employee"))
            )
            .Filterable()
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Selectable()
        )
    </div>

     @Html.Partial("_EmployeeDetails");

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        Grid_OnDataBound = function (e) {
            var grid = $("#EmployeesList").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.select(e.sender.tbody.find("tr:first"));
        }

        Grid_OnRowSelect = function (e) {
            var data = this.dataItem(this.select());
            var empID = data.id;//IMP
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Employee/EmployeeDetails',
                type: "GET",
                //dataType: "JSON",
                data: { 'employeeID': empID }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Upon selecting any employee on my list my OnDataBound and OnRowSelect events send the selected EmployeeID to my EmployeeDetails controller method.

My PartialView:

```
@model Mymvc.Models.vEmployee
@using System.Collections

<div class="col col-xs-6">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeDetails", "Employee"))
    {
        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-8 well">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div id="updateMsg" class="demo-section k-content"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { style = "width: 400px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { style = "width: 400px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { style = "width: 400px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalutationID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SalutationID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["salutationList"], "TitleID", "Title"))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalutationID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["genderList"], "GenderID", "Gender"))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NationalityID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NationalityID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["nationalityList"], "NationalityID", "Nationality"))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EthnicityID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EthnicityID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["ethnicityList"], "EthnicityID", "Ethnicity"))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EthnicityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photograph, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Photograph, new { style = "width: 180px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photograph, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <style>
                    .demo-section {
                        text-align: center;
                        line-height: 4em;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

My Challenge:

I cannot populate my details partialview with model information on selecting an employee on the left list. When I view the SelectedEmployee object in the EmployeeDetails method in debug, the details (lastname, firstname, etc.) can be seen confirming my ajax method is working well.

What am I doing wrong here? Also, is there a better method of presenting list and detail in the same view in mvc?

Thanks!

Comment: rather than using render partial try render action instead.

Comment: pass the model to the @Html.Partial("_EmployeeDetails", Model); since it accepts a model.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Partial("_EmployeeDetails")` only call _EmployeeDetails view. This code cannot call `Controller` `_EmployeeDetails` method.

> **So, as you need ,  Access the view through the controller**

Change `@Html.Partial("_EmployeeDetails")` to `@Html.Action("_EmployeeDetails");`

_EmployeeDetails action can be take selected Id parameter.

```
@Html.Action("_EmployeeDetails", new { id = yourSelectedRowIdValue })
```

You can find the selected id and return from the _EmployeeDetails method spesific detail data.

```
  public ActionResult _EmployeeDetails (int id)
        {
            // var employeeDetail = find _EmployeeDetail using by id                   
            return View (employeeDetail );
        }
```

Comment: using the model gives name 'model' does not exist in the current context even though both view and partialview have the @model myMvc.Models.vEmployee

Comment: Neither suggestion worked. using the model gives error "name 'model' does not exist in the current context" even though both view and partialview have the @model myMvc.Models.vEmployee statement. Using @Html.Action("EmployeeDetails") still produces an unpopulated details partialview. BTW, the method is EmployeeDetails and the partial view is _EmployeeDetails

Comment: I update the answer to your problem. It 's just the right way you have to edit according to your scenario some code

Comment: Still not working as expected with the changes. Could you elaborate on the additional edits?